# How to save image into a folder using WEB.API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm Confused, front end developer saying image saving functionality should be done by back end`WEB.API`. Does he true?

If **YES** how will he send that image to my API whether in the form of `base-64` or any other format.

> **Update**

I need to store Images and videos as well. I think `base-64` size will be very very huge. Doesn't it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can tell him what you want, base-64, formData...

Comment: If the base-64 is very very huge will API handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Front end should use a `FileReader` approach, where end-format will be in `base-64` as you already said. Then on a back end you store this file in a static folder and return only a link to this file(which should be accessible). 
Another approach is that you upload this base-64 to a 3rd-party storage(such as amazon s-3, for example) which will return a link to a file, which can be stored in database.

Comment: If the base-64 is very very huge will API handle it?

Comment: depends on where your API is hosted, does it have enough of resources to parse the data, but usually there are limitations on upload which allows to prevent such things as 'huge files'

Comment: i used godady to store the images and my api are in godady only